# Cannot create a React Native + TypeScript app by following official directions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, tslint

With the following context:

```
$ node -v
v14.8.0

$ npm -v
6.14.7

$ yarn -v
1.21.1

$ tsc -v
Version 4.0.2
```

and following the instructions here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript

I tried to create a `React Native` + `TypeScript` app with the following command:

```
$ npx react-native init app --template react-native-template-typescript
```

but got the following file structure:

[image]

where you can see I don't get any `.tsx` file (I was actually expecting that) even when I used the correspnding `TypeScript` template on the creation command above.

Later on they have the section: **Adding TypeScript to an Existing Project**, but I didn't do the the steps there because what I want to do is not exactly add `TypeScript` to an existing `React Native` project, but just creating a `React Native` project with `TypeScript` from the beginning.

Is there anything wrong I'm doing here?

Thanks for you attention.

Comment: correct way of using typescript with react native recommanded by microsoft https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Native-Starter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using expo for create and develop react-native apps.
Try to install globally on your PC using this command: npm install -g expo-cli.
Then type expo init projectname and you will have this options :

Choose a template:
----- Managed workflow -----
blank                 a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas

> blank (TypeScript)    same as blank but with TypeScript configuration
> tabs (TypeScript)     several example screens and tabs using react-navigation and TypeScript
> ----- Bare workflow -----
> minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started
> minimal (TypeScript)  same as minimal but with TypeScript configuration

and that will works !